# Print the longest word of a string

Tags: c

I wrote the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, max = 0, count = 0, j;
    char str[] = "I'm a programmer";

    for(i = 0; i < str[i]; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            count++;
        else
        {
            if (max < count)
            {
                j = i - count;
                max = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    for(i = j; i < j + max; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

With the intention to find and print the longest word, but does not work when the longest word this in the last as **I'm a programmer** I printed **I'm** instead of **programmer**

How to solve this problem, someone gives me a hand

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: why is your loop condition `i < str[i]` do you really want to stop when the iterator gets to be greater than the ascii value of the character at that index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminating condition of your `for` loop is wrong. It should be:

```
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str) + 1; i++)
```

and also, since at the end of string you **don't** have a `' '`, but you have a `'\0'`, you should change:

```
    if (str[i] != ' ')
```

to:

```
    if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
```

Comment: Should be `i < strlen(str)` (without the `+1`), and since you're already using the equivalent condition `str[i] != '\0'` elsewhere, you might as well use it there too (instead of calling function `strlen`) on every iteration (I'm not the one who down-voted you BTW).

Comment: @barakmanos you are wrong. did you verify your claim before posting it here?

Comment: No, but I honestly think that although the inner condition "covers up for it", there's no need to iterate until (and including) `i = strlen(str)` when at that point `str[i]` is obviously the null-character. Also, you can always use `str[i] != '\0'` instead of `i < strlen(str)`. This is true by the definition of `strlen`, so I see nothing to be wrong about here. It is, however, just a performance improvement (as I stated on my previous comment).

Comment: even if you put `str[i] != '\0'` as termination condition, that would not work. I posted this solution because it's simple and would not confuse the OP. of course you can store the result of `strlen(str)` in a variable, and compare against it, and the asymptotic complexity of the code would be the same as the most optimized algorithm you can think of

Comment: What do you mean `not confuse the OP`? You are already using it elsewhere, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be rather obvious. You only update your longest found word when the character you are inspecting is a space. But there is no space after the longest word in your test string, thus updating code is never exeuted for it.

You can just plop this code after the loop and that should do the trick.

Note however you could have trivially found this by adding mere printfs showing progress of this function.